# How to remove a dot from a dynamically created URL

Tags: regex, perl

In my application, we have a template; where the user can edit and then save it to the DB. The Template is then used by our application to send email invites.

Here is the draft template:

```
Dear {USER FIRST NAME} {USER LAST NAME}: 

{COLLEGE NAME} is providing your access to `example` services, including a dedicated online account. Registration was started for you. 

Without delay, please finish the last few items of your registration. 

Please promptly
finish your registration here: {REGISTRATION URL} 

Also, please {LOG IN} for the first time, to be sure you encounter no issues. If you have questions, Support@example.com is available to help. Once you finish registration, access to your secure account and related example member services will stay with you as you proceed through learning experiences, within and beyond coursework. Thank you
```

Just before sending the invites, the application is replacing the KEYS with real user data. Like `{USER FIRST NAME}` is replaced with `RAHUL` and so on.

The problem which I am facing is ... the user edits the template and adds a dot(.) at the end of the `{REGISTRATION URL}`.

LIKE THIS:

`Please promptly finish your registration here:
{REGISTRATION URL}.`

So, this eventually turns out to be `https://www.example.com/reg?invite_id=1f2sdfg23.` in the email body. The invite code is corrupted now. This is causing the problem to the user as they will be shown an error message. Invite not found page.

**How can I contain this situation. We have informed the user not to do that but I want to preempt the situation even if the user unknowingly does it. I do not want any non-alpha numeric character after the `1f2sdfg23`. It should always be followed by a line-break.**

I tried the below regular expresssion:

```
    $email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}([^a-zA-Z])/$registration_url/ieg;
```

This is working for one instance of dot.

What if the user enters multiple dots 
`Please promptly finish your registration here:
{REGISTRATION URL}...
{REGISTRATION URL}#
etc..`

```
$email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}([^a-zA-Z]+)/$registration_url/ieg;
```

If I extend the filter by allowing multiple characters, then it is removing the unwanted characters. But the problem, re-occurs when the user has promptly given `{REGISTRATION URL}`. The above line of code will remove the line spacing. I do not want that to happen.

**Let me know what best approach I can apply here.**
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for bringing that up. I have corrected it. It was a typo. thanks.

Comment: I can see two solutions - let me know if they work for you
1) add a space after the variable (`$email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}/$registration_url.' '/ieg;`)
2) replace with space everything that is not a whitespace (`$email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}\S+/$registration_url/ieg`)

Comment: Are you talking about the user editing the template, or the value that is replaced into the `{REGISTRATION URL}` placeholder?

Comment: Obviously, you have problems with your template engine:   "So, this _eventually_ turns out to be https://www.example.com/reg?invite_id=1f2sdfg23."   Why not fix it?

Comment: @simbabque I am talking about user editing the template. The URL is generated dynamically in a different process

Comment: I would probably add a single whitespace after this specific placeholder programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wrote in the comment - I can see two solutions

1) add a space after the variable

```
($email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}/$registration_url.' '/ieg;)
```

2) replace with space everything that is not a whitespace

```
($email_body =~ s/\{REGISTRATION URL\}\S+/$registration_url/ieg)
```

Comment: Why the `/e` modifiers?

Comment: I wanted to change the OP code as little as possible.

Comment: @mrzasa The second solution is working as a charm. Had never used \S+.. good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A common convention is to embed URLs in `<brokets>` in plain text to show exactly where the URL begins and ends.

```
No misunderstanding: <http://stackoverflow.com/>!
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best approach would be to check your file before starting the process of replacing those variables. If you expect that line to be `finish your registration here: {REGISTRATION URL}`, then you can check if that line is what you were expecting like this: `$checkEmailTag =~ /\s\{REGISTRATION URL\}$/`. In this case, a preceding space, then your tag and then the end of the line.

If it's not, then you can throw an error stating your file is corrupted and abort the process, or add a space so that user characters won´t hurt your URL allowing you to continue, or any other course of action you see fit.

You don't need to do this for every variable in your file, just for critical variables like this one.